Run .NET Multi-platform App UI development problem run under Windows 10
For testing .NET Multi-platform App UI development projects, I'm using VMware Workstation Pro and Oracle VM VirtualBox to run Visual Studio 2022.
On Windows 11 I can start the project, but it fails on Windows 10. I don't see any errors?
Anyone had a similar problem?
Please see video: on link 5-17-2024 (11-29-37).mp4
I expect to be able to run .NET Multi-platform App UI development projects on Windows 10.

What it the results if you rebuild the projects? and make sure to do it at least 2 times. and please share your visual studio version
